# Xamarin Forms ListVew Binding - Bind ViewCell Label to a Method

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, binding

I'm using Xamarin Forms using an MVVM approach and it works well.

I need a add functionality to an existing ListView to display text when the bound value is a certain value.

Here is the cell that generates the description

```
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}"  x:Name="lblDescription" 
               Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Is there any way of basically only displaying the label is the following function is true (this could be in the view model or code behind) for example:

```
private bool IsDescriptionOk(string description)
    {
       //Look up description possibly in another lookup list
    }
```

id want to bind the visible to the method like:

```
Visible="{Binding IsDescriptionOk}"
```

But as its in the List View, id need to pass in the item index if that makes sense?

Comment: Why would you need to pass an index?  Why couldn't you just return a bool based on the length of the Description property?

Comment: This is just an example, i would want to look up the actual description, for example: if description was "Online", then return false, if description was "In Process" then return true etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there could be multiple ways of solving this kind of issues. One of them could be to use [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters#the-ivalueconverter-interface). Something like this:

```
<ViewCell>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            Text="{Binding Description}"
            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"
            IsVisible="{Binding Description, Converter="{StaticResource ItemStatusToVisiblityConverter}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

However, I think that the `List` should contain only visible items, otherwise you may have multiple empty `ListItems`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - Is there any way i could call a function? as all i'm doing is comparing a list of entries in another object

Comment: You can move this "function" to IValueConverter and pass "another object" to IValueConverter as parameter.

Comment: But once again, why not just to filter the list before assigning it to the List? Sounds like it will make more sense in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, have you got an example of what the IValueConverter would look like in that scenario?. In a simple form so I could build on it. The example above is a bit complicated to get me started.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string _description = null;

public string Description {
  get {
    if (_description == null) {
      // method to fetch/build description 
      _description = GetDescription();
    }
    return _description;
  }

public bool IsDescriptionOK {
  get {
    if ((Description == "Online") || (other values here...)) return false;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm still not sure how you would run the IsdescriptionOk function in ypur example from the xaml binding

Comment: from **YOUR** sample code: `Visible="{Binding IsDescriptionOk}"`